# "For-in loop requires '[String]?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?" but I don't think I am using optionals

Tags: ios, swift, for-in-loop

Here is what I'm trying to do but simplified down:

```
var adictionary = [String:[String]]()
adictionary["A"] = ["B", "C"]
adictionary["B"] = ["A", "C"]
adictionary["C"] = ["A"]
adictionary["D"] = []

var newdic = Array(adictionary.keys).reduce(into: [String: Bool]()) { $0[$1] = false } //I make an arr from a dictionary's keys of type [String:[String]]

for (key, val) in newdic{
     for arr in adictionary[key]{
          if !(adictionary[arr].contains(key)){
               newdic[key] = true
          }
     }
}
```

I get these errors, when I run the above simplified version of the code I am trying to run in an ios app:

main.swift:12:28: error: value of optional type '[String]?' must be unwrapped to a value of type '[String]'
for arr in adictionary[key]{

main.swift:12:28: note: coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'
for arr in adictionary[key]{

main.swift:12:28: note: force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'
for arr in adictionary[key]{

I don't understand, what is wrong with what I am doing? What do these errors mean? It seems like Swift thinks I have an optional somewhere? But I don't see how I do... Any help is much appreciated.

If I change this line: for arr in adictionary[key]{

To: for arr in adictionary[key]!{

It fixes the issues and new errors appear on the if !(a... line. I still don't understand why that fixed it.

Comment: `adictionary[key]` is always an Optional. That’s how dictionaries work.

Comment: As Matt said, you "knowl that there is a value associated with `key` because you got the `key` from the dictionary's keys in the first place, but Swift doesn't "know" that. Accessing a dictionary always returns an optional since there may, or may not be, a value associated with a given key. Force unwrapping makes the problem go away, but nil coalescing with `?? []` is a safer approach. You haven't said what you code is actually trying to achieve, but a `Set` may be a better data structure to use. Ben if you don't there is no need to pre-load `false` ; your dictionary can contain `true`/`nil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift dictionary accesses always return *optional* values, because the lookup will return `nil` if the key doesn't exist.  It is up to you to handle this resulting *optional* is a safe way.  Adding `!` is rarely the right way to fix it because your code will crash if `nil` is returned.

The first time you get an *optional* is here:

```
for arr in adictionary[key] {
```

Again, Swift doesn't know if `key` exists in `adictionary` so it returns an *optional*.  A safe way to fix this is to use the dictionary lookup which returns a `default` value when the key doesn't exist.  In this case, returning an empty array seems like a good choice since your `for` loop will then just do nothing:

```
for arr in adictionary[key, default:[]] {
```

Next, you get an *optional* here:

```
if !(adictionary[arr].contains(key)){
```

Again, you need to decide how to safely handle the fact that `dictionary[arr]` could return `nil`.  The same trick works here: return an empty array if `arr` doesn't exist:

```
if !(adictionary[arr, default:[]].contains(key)){
```

---

Here is the final version of your code:

```
var adictionary = [String:[String]]()
adictionary["A"] = ["B", "C"]
adictionary["B"] = ["A", "C"]
adictionary["C"] = ["A"]
adictionary["D"] = []

var newdic = Array(adictionary.keys).reduce(into: [String: Bool]()) { $0[$1] = false } //I make an arr from a dictionary's keys of type [String:[String]]
print(newdic)

for key in newdic.keys {
    for arr in adictionary[key, default:[]] {
        if !(adictionary[arr, default:[]].contains(key)){
               newdic[key] = true
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand this part: “In this case, returning an empty array seems like a good choice since your for loop“ why do I want to return [] and exit my function? If that key really doesn’t exist as a key for the other dictionary, I think I would rather it simply skip it and continue, so a continue statement would make more sense. I’m going to look up what default does in swift and come back to this. Also to look up what nil coalescing is, I don’t understand that either

Comment: `default:` provides the value that the dictionary lookup returns when the key doesn't exist.  In the case of my code, an empty array will be returned which does exactly what you want.  The inner for loop will just be skipped since there are no elements in the array and the code will continue on to the next key.

Comment: “if !(adictionary[arr, default:[]].contains(key)){“ So this is basically like using a nil coalescing operator? Its kinda like saying “?? []” , am I understanding it right? And thank you for teaching me

Comment: Yes, it's very much like the nil coalescing operator `if !((adictionary[arr] ?? []).contains(key))) {`, but it has the added benefit that you can append to it.  If you created a new dictionary to count letters in a word, you could say `dict[letter, default: 0] += 1` and the first time you see a letter, it would create the dictionary entry and increment it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar approach without having your mentioned problem.

```
var adictionary = [String:[String]]()
adictionary["A"] = ["B", "C"]
adictionary["B"] = ["A", "C"]
adictionary["C"] = ["A"]
adictionary["D"] = []

var newdic = Array(adictionary.keys).reduce(into: [String: Bool]()) { $0[$1] = false }

let notEmptValues = adictionary.values.filter { $0.count > 0 }.reduce([], +)
let duplicates = Array(Set(notEmptValues.filter { i in notEmptValues.filter { $0 == i }.count > 1 })).sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
if let result = adictionary.first(where: { $0.value.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 }) == duplicates })?.key {
    newdic[result] = true
}

print(newdic)
```